# Reverse string find_first_not_of

Tags: c++, string, find

I have a `std::string` and I want to find the position of the first character that:

- Is different from all the following characters: `' '`, `'\n'` and `'\t'`.
- Has lower position from that indicated by me.

So, for example if I have the following `string` and position:

```
string str("AAA BBB=CCC DDD");
size_t pos = 7;
```

I want to have the possibility to use a method like this:

```
size_t res = find_first_of_not_reverse(str, pos, " \n\t");
// now res = 4, because 4 is the position of the space character + 1
```

How can I do?

Comment: The space character is at position 3. The first B is at position 4. And why would you want the position of the space character? You asked for the position of a character that's *not* in the given list.

Comment: I am not sure I understand your question. Should it be: 
Is one of the following characters: ' ', '\n' and '\t'?

Comment: @JuanBesa I want to find the first 'B' in my example, because I specified the position 7. If my pos is str.lenght - 1 the res will be the position of the first 'D'.

Comment: @gliderkite- My apologies, I misread your question.

Comment: I think templatetypedef was on the right track. Should you not just `find_last_of` your list of characters, and add 1?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Bo commented, templatetypedef's answer was 99% of the way there; we just need [`std::string::find_last_of`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/find_last_of) rather than `std::string::find_last_not_of`:

```
#include <cassert>
#include <string>

std::string::size_type find_first_of_not_reverse(
    std::string const& str,
    std::string::size_type const pos,
    std::string const& chars)
{
    assert(pos > 1);
    assert(pos < str.size());

    std::string::size_type const res = str.find_last_of(chars, pos - 1) + 1;
    return res == pos ? find_first_of_not_reverse(str, pos - 1, chars)
         : res ? res
         : std::string::npos;
}

int main()
{
    std::string const str = "AAA BBB=CCC DDD";
    std::string const chars = " \n\t";
    std::string::size_type res = find_first_of_not_reverse(str, 7, chars); // res == 4
    res = find_first_of_not_reverse(str, 2, chars); // res == npos
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I was curious why basic_string does not define rfind_first_of and friends myself. I think it should. Regardless here is a non-recursive (see ildjarn's answer) implementation that should fulfill the requirements of this question. It compiles but I've not tested it.

```
std::string delims = " \n\t";
reverse_iterator start = rend()-pos-1, found = 
std::find_first_of(start,rend(),delims.begin(),delims.end());
return found==rend()?npos:pos-(found-start);
```

To be like rfind pos needs to be set to size() if it's npos or greater than size().

PS: I think this question could benefit from some editing. For one "find_first_of_not_reverse" is pretty misleading. It should be rfind_first_of I think (and then add 1 to the result.)